# I am having trouble pushing data to another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot get my values to go to another html page. I validated the fields and after the fields are filled and we click save the data doesnt go to the new html.

In the new html only Welcome is displayed.

This is the first HTML where we put out name

```js
function parse() {
  var n = document.getElementById("nam").value;
  localStorage.setItem("textvalue", n);
  return false;

}

function validations(form) {
  function trimfield(str) {
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  }

  var errors = [];
  var n = document.getElementById("nam").value;
  if (n == "") {
    errors.push("Enter Name \n");
  }

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    var msg = "Errors : \n\n";
    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
      msg = msg + errors[i];
    }
    alert(msg);
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>

<head>
  <title> User Registration Page</title>
  <link href="UserRegistration.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <form action="UserInfo.html" method="POST" onsubmit="return validations(this);" onsubmit="return parse();">
    <div class="name">
      Name : <input type="text" id="nam" name="fullName">
    </div>
  
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the second html that i am having trouble displaying my Name(UserInfo.html)

```
<html> 
    <body> 
        Welcome : <span id= "result"> </span>
        <script>
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("textvalue");


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That should work fine...

Comment: why you have 2 onsubmit event handler ?

Comment: Double on submit listeners? Not sure if that's correct. You should stick with one.

Comment: @nAviD one is for validation and the other one is after the validation to send the data to the new html.

Comment: @JackBashford The name is not displaying for some reason

Comment: @Adam the second one replaces the first one

Comment: With `onsubmit= "return validations(this);"`, as long as the validations func does not `return false` it will go ahead with the submit

Comment: @nAviD well, if i try to do submit it before the fields are filled, it will show a validation error.

Comment: The submit button isn't in the form, so it won't work.

Comment: @Barmar That was a mistake in my end while writing the question. The button is inside the </form>

Comment: BTW, JavaScript has a built-in `String.prototype.trim()` method that does the same thing as `trimfield()`.

Comment: @Adam I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use two onsubmit attributes. Aggregate all your functions inside one and then perform it. I've merged the parse function with the validations. It's the same thing. Also, you never submitted your form. That's why the functions also don't get triggered. Use a submit button too. It should be inside the form tag. Not outside

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML > 
<html>
<head> 
<title> User Registration Page</title>
<link href="UserRegistration.css" rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script>

function trimfield(str) { 
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''); 
}
function validations(form) {
   var errors = [] ; 
   var n = document.getElementById("nam").value; 
   if (n == "") {
      errors.push("Enter Name \n"); 
   }

   if (errors.length > 0) {
       var msg = "Errors : \n\n" ; 
       for (var i = 0 ; i<errors.length; i++ ){ 
            msg = msg + errors[i]; 
       }
       alert(msg);
   }else{
       localStorage.setItem("textvalue", n); 
       alert(localStorage.getItem("textvalue"));
       return false;  
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="UserInfo.html" method="POST"  onsubmit="validations(this);">
       <div class = "name" >
        Name :   <input type ="text" id="nam" name="fullName" > 
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, no idea where you are calling trimfield. Declare it outside any other functions and use it wherever you want.

Comment: I tried the same way you did it and it still the same. It directs me to the other page but it doesnt show the name field

Comment: maybe there is something wrong in the userinfo.html page

Comment: That page is fine. Try a hard reload via CTRL + SHIFT + R. Maybe you have the script in the cache.

Comment: okay just did that and the alert of the alert(localStorage.getItem("textvalue")); works. but it does not go to the userinfo page .

Comment: I just checked the user info page and the name is there but its not navigating form the htm page though

Comment: Working for me, the exact code here. @Adam Try hard reloading like i told you

Answer (score -1):

I tried to fix every mistakes you have made :

```
function parse() {
  var n = document.getElementById("nam").value;
  localStorage.setItem("textvalue", n);
  return true;

}

function validations(form) {
  function trimfield(str) {
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  }

  var errors = [];
  var n = document.getElementById("nam").value;
  if (n == "") {
    errors.push("Enter Name \n");
  }

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    var msg = "Errors : \n\n";
    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
      msg = msg + errors[i];
    }
    alert(msg);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

the html :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>

<head>
  <title> User Registration Page</title>
  <link href="UserRegistration.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <form action="UserInfo.html" method="POST" onsubmit="if(validations(this)) return parse(); else return false;">
    <div class="name">
      Name : <input type="text" id="nam" name="fullName" />
    </div>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```